# Why Form not get submitted after validation error message?

Tags: jsf, ajax4jsf

I have a form to update user's information, if validation fails, it displays error message and after correcting the error input, the form doesn't get submit why?. Without error message, it submits well.

```
<h:form id="update" prependId="false">
    <h:outputText value="Name: " styleClass="titleBlue"/>
    <h:inputText id="contactName" value="#{serviceBean.contactName}" maxlength="50" size="15" style="width:200px" >
        <f:validateLength minimum="3" maximum="50"/>             
    </h:inputText>              
    <h:message for="contactName" style="color:red;font-size: 0.70em;"/>
    <h:outputText value="Title: " styleClass="titleBlue"/>
    <h:inputText id="contactTitle" value="#{serviceBean.contactTitle}" maxlength="50" size="15" style="width:200px">
        <f:validateLength minimum="3" maximum="50"/>
    </h:inputText>
    <h:message for="contactTitle" style="color:red;font-size: 0.70em;"/>
    <h:panelGroup style="display:block; text-align:center">
        <a4j:commandButton action="#{serviceBean.update}" styleClass="titleBold" value="Update"/>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Does the form submit correctly if the input (which caused the validation error) is corrected?

Comment: Isn't that how it is supposed to work? Don't submit if it fails...

Comment: form doesn't submit after the input is corrected

Comment: Could you show us some code, or a live link?

Comment: You should edit your question and post some of your code...

Answer (score 0):

Why does form does not get submit after showing the alert message :
What I need id if the value is null set the default value and submit the form.